# SQLAlchemy Error: This operation requires only one Table or entity be specified as the target

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete a row and its parent row from a table:

This is my code:

```
result = session.query(TableA, TableB). \
join(TableB). \
filter(TableA.ColumnA == 'something').delete()
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
"sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This operation requires only one Table or entity be specified as the target."
```

I've also tried to execute this code

```
result = session.query(TableA). \
join(TableB). \
filter(TableA.ColumnA == 'something').delete()
```

But in this way only tableA row was deleted.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

i execute:

```
result = session.query(TableA, TableB). \
    join(TableB). \
    filter(TableA.ColumnA == 'something').one()
```

And then:

```
del_result_A = session.delete(result.TableA)
del_result_B = session.delete(result.TableB)
session.commit()
```